# Remotely Killing a process in 1 shot

Tags: vbscript

I have this code to remotely kill a certain process on 5 servers. My problem is that i want to cut it short and kill the process in all servers in 1 click. The code now asks if i am sure i want to kill the process, then kills the process, then asks if i want to proceed to the next server. i would like to just have a messge saying, "Killing process on all servers" and done

```
`Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strProcessKill, item
Dim strComputer(4)
Dim ans, killFLag

strComputer(0) = "server1"
strComputer(1) = "server2"
strComputer(2) = "server3"
strComputer(3) = "server4"
strComputer(4) = "server5"

    strProcessKill = "'notepad.exe'" 



For item = 0 To 4 Step 1

if MsgBox("Are you sure you want to kill " & strProcessKill & " on " & strCOmputer(item) & "?" , vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes then
    killFLag = 1
end if


if KillFlag = 1 then
    msgbox "KILLING PROCESS ON" & strComputer(item)
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer(item) & "\root\cimv2") 

    Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & strProcessKill)
        For Each objProcess in colProcess
            objProcess.Terminate()
        Next 
    WSCript.Echo "Just killed process " & strProcessKill & " on " & strComputer(item)   

else

WScript.Quit 

end if
```

Next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the for loop down so that you are not prompted for each server. Something like this should work

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strProcessKill, item
Dim strComputer(4)
Dim ans, killFLag

strComputer(0) = "server1"
strComputer(1) = "server2"
strComputer(2) = "server3"
strComputer(3) = "server4"
strComputer(4) = "server5"


    strProcessKill = "'notepad.exe'" 

if MsgBox("Are you sure you want to kill " & strProcessKill & " on all servers?" , vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes then
    killFLag = 1
end if


if KillFlag = 1 then
    msgbox "KILLING PROCESS ON ALL SERVERS" 
    For item = 0 To 4 Step 1
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer(item) & "\root\cimv2") 

        Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & strProcessKill)
            For Each objProcess in colProcess
                objProcess.Terminate()
            Next 

    next
    msgBox "Done"
else

WScript.Quit 

end if
```

Comment: EXACTLY what i needed, i was thinking too hard lol. Thanks so much for the help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: **UPDATE**  code for some reason isnt working anymore, nothing has changed. when script is run it gets up to the msg box "killing process on all servers" i click ok and the script seems to quit without anything happening. Any ideas??

Comment: you can try logging to a text file to see what is happening, or even just adding some wscript.echo within the for loop to see where the script is ending.